# Razor Form Model - One of two properties mandatory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know that the following is not possible, but is there a similar way to achieve that one of two properties has to be filled out? In other words, the user has to enter either a UserName or an Email.

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required(OrField=Email)]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(OrField=UserName)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a [custom model validation attribute](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260177/Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-ASP-NET-MVC3), optionally with a client-side adapter to make javascript validate things, or you could just handle this in controller code:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(model.UserName) && 
       string.IsNullOrWhitespace(model.Email)) 
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Either a username or email must be provided.");
    }
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {...}
    else {...}
}
```

In this particular case, a more elegant solution may be to accept either an email or a username in the `Username` field, and intelligently detect which one the user provided.